# Get string to TextView from the object pulled from JSON

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I have a problem populating separate `TextView` with the content from the same JSON.

Each fragment is having a `ListView` populated by adapter. Data is pulled from `JSON` file. First, I am importing data from `JSONArray` and adding it to object `Article` created separately:

```
JSONObject e = articlesJsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);
    String title = e.getString("title");
    int itemId = e.getInt("id");
    Article article = new Article(title, itemId);
    articles.add(article);
```

Then, I have created `ArticleAdapter` where I am putting this content into `ListView`. This works.

In my `Activity`, I am then creating a list out of that:

```
  ListView mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list);
  mAdapter = new ArticleAdapter (getActivity(), new ArrayList<Article>());
  mainListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Now, I would like to create a TextView in the same activity, which would pull "title" from the first object Article in the list.

```
TextView featuredImageTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.featuredimage_title);
featuredImageTitle.setText(??????????);
```

Should I pass this info from adapter? Or from `Article` object? Or should I read it from the 0 position in the list I have built for the `ListView`?

Here is my full code which imports the content and creates the object.

public final class QueryUtils {

```
public QueryUtils() {
}

// Returns new URL object from the URL String
private static URL createUrl(String stringUrl) {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(stringUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem building URL", e);
    }
    return url;
}

// makes a HTTP request to the URL and returns String
private static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
    String jsonResponse = "";
    // If the URL is null, then return early.
    if (url == null) {
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        // If the request was successful (response code 200),
        // then read the input stream and parse the response.
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
            }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem retrieving articles JSON.", e);
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        if (inputStream != null) {
            // Closing the input stream could throw an IOException, which is why
            // the makeHttpRequest(URL url) method signature specifies than an IOException
            // could be thrown.
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    return jsonResponse;

}

// Query the JSON info and return a list of {@link Article} objects.
public static List<Article> extractArticles(String requestUrl) {
    // Create URL object
    URL url = createUrl(requestUrl);

    // Perform HTTP request to the URL and receive a JSON response back
    String jsonResponse = null;
    try {
        jsonResponse = makeHttpRequest(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem making the HTTP request.", e);
    }

    List<Article> articles = extractFromJson(jsonResponse);

    // Return the list of articles
    return articles;
}

/**
 * Convert the {@link InputStream} into a String which contains the
 * whole JSON response from the server.
 */
private static String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    if (inputStream != null) {
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            output.append(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    }
    return output.toString();
}

/**
 * Return a list of {@link Article} objects that has been built up from
 * parsing a JSON response.
 */
public static List<Article> extractFromJson(String articleJSON) {
        // If the JSON string is empty or null, then return early.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(articleJSON)) {
            return null;
        }

        // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding earthquakes to
        List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();

    // Try to parse JSON response. If there's a problem with the way the JSON
    // is formatted, a JSONException exception object will be thrown.
    // Catch the exception so the app doesn't crash, and print the error message to the logs.
    try {
        // Create a JSONArray from the JSON response string
        JSONArray articlesJsonResponse = new JSONArray(articleJSON);

        // For each article in the articleArray, create an Article object
        for (int i=0; i < articlesJsonResponse.length(); i++) {
            // Parse the response given by the json string and
            // build up a list of article objects with the corresponding data.

            JSONObject e = articlesJsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = e.getString("title");
            int articleId = e.getInt("id");
            int views = e.getInt("views");
            int comments = e.getInt("comments");
            String thumb = e.getString("image");
            String url = e.getString("url");
            String date = e.getString("date");
            Article article = new Article(title, articleId, views, comments, thumb, url, date);
            articles.add(article);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
        // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
        // with the message from the exception.
        Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing JSON results", e);
    }

    // Return the list of articles
    return articles;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access only the first object title on the list

get the 0 positions of your list but also check if list size > 0 to not give Index exception

like

```
  if(articles.size > 0){

    featuredImageTitle.setText(articles.get(0).getTitle)
 }
```

but if you need to get the title from the clicked object in the list you need to implement OnItemClickListener to you listView

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
        featuredImageTitle.setText(articles.get(position).getTitle);
    }
```

and be sure to set `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on the first parent layout inside the list

Comment: Thank you Ahmed. It seems I am missing something in logic. If I try with your code from first example, "articles" is not recognized in the Activity, ie its marked as Cannot resolve symbol
        if (articles.size>0) {
            featuredImageTitle.setText(articles.get(0).getArticleTitle);

If I introduce it at the beginning of the Activity:
private Article articles;

Then I am getting "cannot resolve symbol on "size" and "get"?

Comment: I think you are using Array , prefer to use List instead

Comment: List<Article> articles = new ArrayList();

Comment: Hm, nope. Still Cannot resolve symbol for .size and .getTitle. I have updated my question above, I hope that will help.

Comment: Here in your QueryUtils you are using extractFromJson to convert the string json to List so you can use it in your activity

Comment: QueryUtils.extractFromJson("pass your json string").get(0).getTitle

Comment: Well, it doesn't work this way. But probably there is some problem on my side, either with passing variables from one class to another, or with the way how I am asking the question. Back to the study book for me, Ahmed thanks for now, I will find the solution.